# After migrating to Androidx, butterknife doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, androidx, butterknife

-After I migrated my android project to Androidx I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: core
Affected Modules: app
```

-After Rebuilding it I get this:

```
Could not find core.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.0.0/core-1.0.0.jar
```

-But after excluding butterknife from my gradle everything gets fine and I get no error.

-I tried this before and did not work:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

-I have used below code in gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

-butterknife dependencies code:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
```